# Avoiding SwiftUI Hang on loading list of images from CoreData

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data, freeze, lazyhgrid

The following has a SwiftUI Hang for several seconds.

This code is copy-pasted and makes up one of the tabs of my simple app.  Hang occurs once when first showing this tab.

Number of images is ~150; image size 1920x1080.

```
struct PhotosView : View
{
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\Photo.date, order: .reverse)], animation: .default)
    private var photos: FetchedResults<Photo>

    @State private var gridHeight = 180.0

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            ScrollView(.horizontal)
            {
                LazyHGrid(rows: [GridItem(.fixed(gridHeight))], alignment: .top, spacing: 0)
                {
                    ForEach(photos)
                    { photo in
                        if let data = photo.filteredData
                        {
                            Image(data: data)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 200)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that using the `LazyHGrid` only a handful would be loaded initially (only one and almost a half fit on screen currently).

How I can improve performance?

Comment: Instead of saving images as data in CoreData save a URL, AsyncImage won’t cause hangs.

Comment: @loremipsum Introducing URLs would add quite some logic. Could there not be a solution using CoreData data?

Comment: Make the images smaller, try running your app on an older device it would probably hang a lot more since you are pulling all this data on the main actor.

Comment: I don't even know what Photo contains, but provided that it contained images as `Data`, that sounds like a bad idea.  As lorem ipsum suggests, I would save paths to them in the database.

Comment: @ElTomato Why would it be bad with Allows External Storage option on?

Comment: IMHO, `Allows External Storage option on` is not a bad idea per se, **but**
 as mentioned before, it is better to store the url to the images data in files, and
 let the efficient File system (FileManager) deal with them.
 Just the reduction to the size of the database using this approach can
 improve performance significantly. Note I have not performed any time/memory tests, this is just based on my own opinion and logic. Note also, there is also the newer `SwiftData`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine What does Allows External Storage do other than "store the url to the images data in files, and let the efficient File system (FileManager) deal with them" by CoreData which results in a "reduction to the size of the database"???

Comment: I'm just simply saying that, when the images are stored in files, it is not under the storage of CoreData database.
This implies that the size of the database is much reduced, and so (IMHO) more efficient when used.
See this other SO post, [Allows External Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372449/core-data-allows-external-storage-performance-on-large-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the fetch will load every `filteredData` into memory even if it is not being displayed. You need to use a custom `NSFetchRequest` with [`includesPropertyValues`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506387-includespropertyvalues) set to `false` and then make a subview that takes the object and accesses `filteredData` causing it only to be loaded for that one object when it appears (`body` will be called at this time). You would also benefit from a predicate that searches for non-nil data that would help avoid the `if` in your `body` which can cause slow downs. E.g. something like:

```
struct PhotoView: View {
    @ObservedObject var photo: Photo

    var body: View {
        Image(data: photo.filteredData!)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }
}

// this could be moved to a lazy var in an extension of Photo
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Photo> = {
    let fr = Photo.fetchRequest()
    fr.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "filteredData != nil")
    fr.includesPropertyValues = false
    fr.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(\Photo.date, ascending: false)]
    return fr
}

struct PhotosView : View
{
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, animation: .default)
    private var photos: FetchedResults<Photo>

...
        ForEach(photos) { photo in
            PhotoView(photo: photo)
        }
...
```

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223220/259521) to another question for more detail.

Comment: Does speed things up; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue because I couldn't set some details for native LazyViews.
Therefore, I had to create my own LazyView, although it wasn't that convenient.

I can't provide the entire code, but here are some details:

- Set an index to load items, for example, 5 items or 7 items.
- If the second/third last item appears using `.onAppear`, then load the next item or the next group of items.
- `.onAppear` will be called as soon as the item is shown, even if it's just 1% visible. Therefore, you may need to set some offset for that with additional code (for instance, if the item is shown more than 30%, load the next item)

p.s.
If you're not supporting iPads, a size of 1920x1080 is unnecessarily large for iPhones